# Explaination for foobar challenege level 2

Tags: java

I'm doing foobar's challenge and im stuck on this question in level 2 ! I'm not getting what the question is. 
Please explain me what the question is.

As Commander Lambda's personal assistant, you've been assigned the task of configuring the **LAMBCHOP doomsday device's axial orientation gears**. It should be pretty simple - just add **gears** to create the appropriate rotation **ratio**. But the problem is, due to the layout of the LAMBCHOP and the complicated system of beams and pipes supporting it, the pegs that will support the gears are fixed in place.

The LAMBCHOP's engineers have given you lists identifying the placement of groups of pegs along various support beams. You need to place a gear on each peg (otherwise the gears will collide with unoccupied pegs). The engineers have plenty of gears in all different sizes stocked up, so you can choose gears of any size, from a radius of 1 on up. Your goal is to build a system where the last gear rotates at twice the rate (in revolutions per minute, or rpm) of the first gear, no matter the direction. Each gear (except the last) touches and turns the gear on the next peg to the right.

Given a list of distinct positive integers named pegs representing the location of each peg along the support beam, write a function answer(pegs) which, if there is a solution, returns a list of two positive integers a and b representing the numerator and denominator of the first gear's radius in its simplest form in order to achieve the goal above, such that radius = a/b. The ratio a/b should be greater than or equal to 1. Not all support configurations will necessarily be capable of creating the proper rotation ratio, so if the task is impossible, the function answer(pegs) should return the list [-1, -1].

For example, if the pegs are placed at [4, 30, 50], then the first gear could have a radius of 12, the second gear could have a radius of 14, and the last one a radius of 6. Thus, the last gear would rotate twice as fast as the first one. In this case, pegs would be [4, 30, 50] and answer(pegs) should return [12, 1].

The list pegs will be given sorted in ascending order and will contain at least 2 and no more than 20 distinct positive integers, all between 1 and 10000 inclusive.
Inputs:
    (int list) pegs = [4, 30, 50]
Output:
    (int list) [12, 1]

Inputs:
    (int list) pegs = [4, 17, 50]
Output:
    (int list) [-1, -1]

Thank you in advance ! Hope someone will come up with explaination.

Comment: where is that from?

Comment: It's from Google's foobar challenge .

Comment: So basically you're being asked to fit two gears on the start and end such that the end one is half the radius of the first. Then you must also state the radius of the gears in the middle. If no such configuration is possible, you have to return -1.

Comment: Sorry, you don't need to return the middle gear sizes.

Comment: Yes ,but i want a bit more deep explanation about how it is assembled and possibly a diagram (link) for clear understanding of problem .Thanks a lot for your reply and valuable time @weston

Comment: It's just some gears in a row but have you tried drawing a diagram yourself? Have you tried solving for the simple cases first (2 gears first, then 3 gears). Look for a pattern as you add gears.

Comment: Yes i did drew a rough diagram having gears and axial but i dont know what a peg is and where to position it ,so got stuck !Anyways thanks @weston

Comment: Pegs are the axles. They are what the gears rotate about.

Comment: Yes ,you were right @weston

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understood the problem as,
There are pegs and gears are on it with the condition that the first gears raduis should be double the last so that the speed of the last gear will be double the first.[How the device looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve59L.jpg)

So i have to program this satisfying 2 condtions 
1 - The raduis of the middle pegs should always be greater than 1
2 - radius(last Gear) should always be radius(First Gear/2)  This condition should satisfy

Given: 
   n pegs, numbered from 1 to n

Let:
   d(n) - the distance between peg[n] and peg[n+1] 
   x - the size of the first gear
   y - the size of the last gear

Constraint: 
   x = 2y

Then:
if n is odd,  y = d(n-1) - d(n-2) + d(n-3) - ... - d(1) + x
if n is even, y = d(n-1) - d(n-2) + d(n-3) - ... + d(1) - x

and here is the code for this :

def answer(pegs):

```
maximum = pegs[1] - pegs[0] - 1
for x in xrange(1, maximum):
    gear_sizes = [x]
    for peg in xrange(1, len(pegs)):
        gear_sizes.append(pegs[peg] - (pegs[peg-1] + gear_sizes[-1]))

    if any(d <= 0 for d in gear_sizes):
        continue

    if x == 2 * gear_sizes[-1]:
        return [x, 1]

    if x+1 == 2 * gear_sizes[-1]:
        return [(x * 3) + 1, 3]
    if x+2 == 2 * gear_sizes[-1]:
        return [(x * 3) + 2, 3]

return [-1, -1]
```